# Alternative to calling stored procedure for multiple records

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005

I have a `SSRS` report which displays a summary table of records. After I click on one of the records, it goes to the individual report of the record which has multiple lines on it that are configurable.

Now I have to add a column in the summary table report that displays the line numbers that are checked on the individual report. There is already a scalar function in the database that is used to determine whether a line is checked based on the `GUID` of the record and an internal label string given for the line. There is also a stored procedure that gets the line number to be displayed on the report from the database.

So for getting the line numbers to display on the summary report, I am planning on calling a `UDF` for each record in the stored procedure that gets the records for the summary report. But there is a problem in this case since I cannot call a stored procedure from a function. I need to call the stored procedure that gets the line number to display for each record, since the line numbers can be be unique for different records.

I then thought of converting the function to a stored procedure but then that would mean I would need to call it for each record which would require a `WHILE` loop or cursor. I am not sure whether this loop would be the best possible solution for my case. I cannot change the stored procedure that gets the line numbers to a function since it is used by many other reports before this and would require making changes to the stored procedures of all those reports.

Comment: can you rework the "stored procedure that gets the line number to be displayed on the report" as a function?

Comment: As I mentioned it would require me to make changes to all reports that already use it. I just checked the dependencies in SQL Server Management studio and there are like atleast 30 other stored procedures using it.

Comment: you can leave the stored procedure in place and just replicate the algorithm as a function

Comment: Ok, so do you mean creating a function just to use in this specific case?